# Get some product data in the body for WooCommerce Single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to pull the Product ID for the product being viewed in order to pass that ID into TrustPilot's widget to display reviews for that product.

I've tried creating a Snippet with this code:

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id()
```

But I got an error and - I'll be honest - I don't really understand what I was doing! I've been browsing for solutions for most of the day, so I'm hoping someone might be kind enough to help!

As mentioned, the aim is to be able to populate the `data-sku="xxxxxxxx"` field in a TrustPilot "TrustBox" - a javascript tool that pulls & presents reviews from trustpilot. The ID will need to be updated in the HTML for the element, I think.

The whole of the TrustPilot code is shown below:

**Add this to Header**

```
<!-- TrustBox script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
<!-- End TrustBox script -->
```

**Add this to body, where you want the widget to appear**

```
<!-- TrustBox widget - Product Reviews SEO -->
<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="5717796816f630043868e2e8" data-businessunit-id="5d472f87ff988700011c73b8" data-style-height="700px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-sku="487" data-name="10 Plantshake Pack" data-review-languages="en">
  <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/foga.co" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
</div>
<!-- End TrustBox widget -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

To get the product ID in single product pages, you can use: `$product_id = get_the_ID();`

To be sure to get the product object in single product pages, you can use:

```
$product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
```

Or even better:

```
global $product;

if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
}
```

Now you can use a hooked function, to insert all the related code in single product pages. Your javscript will be populated dynamically with the product name and sku:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'action_before_single_product', 5 );
function  action_before_single_product(){
    global $product;
    
    $id   = $product->get_id(); // Product Id
    $sku  = $product->get_sku(); // Product sku
    $name = $product->get_name(); // Product name
    ?> 
    <!-- TrustBox widget - Product Reviews SEO -->
    <div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="5717796816f630043868e2e8" data-businessunit-id="5d472f87ff988700011c73b8" data-style-height="700px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-sku="<?php echo $sku; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $name; ?>" data-review-languages="en">
      <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/foga.co" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
    </div>
    <!-- End TrustBox widget -->
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Loic - thanks so much for taking the time to answer in so much detail!

Can I ask you to clarify where/how these various bits of text should be deployed?

Comment: Hmm - sorry I'm still struggling! I've tried putting the code (the longer, last piece of code) directly into the product page and I'm seeing this:
get_id()
$sku = $product->get_sku();
$name = $product->get_name();

?>
Just above the widget, which is not populated with the data, implying that the ID isn't pulling in... Any further ideas?

Comment: Probably not! I'm putting it into the product layout template (and I've also tested straight into the product description...) Where should i be putting it?

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec - it works! Sort of... It's pulling through correctly which is amazing! However, the reviews widget is just forced to the top of the page by the function. How can I insert the actual widget at a suitable location on the page and still dynamically populate it?

Comment: @OllieThirlwell-Pearce Where exactly you will want it to be?, In what location on the product page?

Comment: Ideally I would be able to include the TrustPilot code at any point on the page (I have a few different product layout templates) and the code would dynamically populate. Is it possible to do this? Or does the whole element need to be added through the php?

Comment: @OllieThirlwell-Pearce It should be better added via a hooked function (like in my answer code)… You can see some related available hooks starting with `do_action()` in the [template `content-single-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/templates/content-single-product.php) or you can also embed the code in a shortcode…